# Change the CErtificate fields encoding from printableString to UTF8String java code

Tags: java, encoding, certificate

I am generating a certificate in java using the bouncy castle library.  All the fields in my generated certificate are encoded in `PrintableString`. But, there are many characters not supported by this encoding type. So, I want to change my encoding type to `UTF8String`  I say we should change the default `directoryString` attribute. But, I didn't find a java code which can do this. Who can help me?
This is what I get while executing the command: `openssl asn1parse -in test.cer`

[View image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIJAS.png)
this is the code where i am generating the certificate , using the bouncycustle and sun.security libs :
 `String certificate = ca.getCert();
        byte[] cert_bytes = certificate.getBytes();
        cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
        X509Certificate cr = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(cert_bytes));
        cr.getKeyUsage();
        X509CertInfo info = new X509CertInfo();
        Date from = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 5);
        Date to = cal.getTime();
        CertificateValidity interval = new CertificateValidity(from, to);
        BigInteger sn = new BigInteger(64, new SecureRandom());
        org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name x500Name = req.getSubject();
        X500Name x500name_subject = new X500Name(getX500Field(COMMON_NAME, x500Name), getX500Field(COUNTRY, x500Name),
                getX500Field(LOCALE, x500Name), getX500Field(ORGANIZATION, x500Name),
                getX500Field(ORGANIZATION_UNIT, x500Name), getX500Field(STATE, x500Name));
        X500Principal principal = cr.getSubjectX500Principal();
        X500Name x500namecert = new X500Name(principal.getName());
        X500Name x500name_issuer = new X500Name(x500namecert.getCommonName(), x500namecert.getCountry(),
                x500namecert.getOrganization(), x500namecert.getOrganizationalUnit());`

Comment: `directoryString` is not an attribute; `DirectoryString` (capital D) is a type used for many attributes, including the two you show. The encoding for the (at least two) Distinguished Names in a cert created by Bouncy depends on your code; show a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). PS: you can get a less bulky display of the DN(s) including types with e.g. `openssl x509 -noout {-subject|-issuer} -nameopt {oneline|multiline},show_type -in file [-inform der]`

Comment: Thank you fro the answer but i didn't get how to solve my problem ...

Comment: That's a comment not an answer; on StackExchange there's a difference. I can't say how to solve your problem because I don't know what caused it, that's why I asked you to show code that creates the cert (or at least the DN(s)). Maybe should also specify version; I don't _think_ this has changed but sometimes they change things I don't notice. (I use the `org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X500Name(String)` ctor which does encode as UTF8String, with limited exceptions per rfc5280 etc.)

Comment: Hello .. so this is the code where i am generating the certificate ...